# Returning to previous screen after receiver activity

Tags: android

I have a app that has a activity that can be started from the start
menu and a activity that is started by a broadcast receiver.

[image]

Now on boot , if the receiver is called , the "event viewer" activity is
started...after backing out of this activity user returns to previous
screen (could be homescreen or whatever user was doing) .. this is how it
should be.

But if i start the "main" activity from the main launcher, and press
the home button to go back to the home screen..the problem begins.
Now if the receiver is called the "event viewer" activity is shown.
if the user backs out of the "event viewer" activity (or i call finish() ) it will show the "main" activity(still running in background) instead of the previous thing the user was doing (like home screen).

This is not how i want it..because it causes users after dismissing a
calendar event (the purpose of my app) to return to eg the settings
from the main app..

If i call finish() in onpause , it works ok...but that is not the way
it should work.

Any clues?

Hope the problem is clear , since english isn't my first language i
found it hard to explain the problem :-)

Thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your receiver, use the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //... bla bla bla

    Intent in = new Intent(context, IndependentActivity.class);
    in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(in);

    //... bla bla bla
}
```

In your manifest, provide a taskAffinity for your IndependentActivity.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".IndependentActivity"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:taskAffinity="com.example.independantactivty.ind" >
    </activity>
```

I have excluded it from the Recents but that is totally optional.

Comment: Intent flags are indeed the way to go +1

Comment: GREAT!!! works perfect. I already had the NEW_TASK flag...but not the taskaffinity... thanks helped me a lot..

Answer (score 0):

It's generally unwise in my opinion to launch activities unless the user has elected to run the app (widget press, notification select, launcher, etc). Your example is just one reason why suddenly changing the activity when the user isn't expecting it might cause problems.

If the user isn't using the app the best way to get their attention is through the status bar notification system.

Comment: In some cases i think it is the way to go..like when receiving a sms, or in my case a calendar event.

Answer (score 0):

put

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1000) {
        if (resultCode == 1) {
            Main.this.finish();
        }

    }}
```

in your main activity and in your other activity, put this.setResult(1); before call yourOtherActivity.this.finish()

I think it's that. What's your first language?

Comment: thanks, but did not work :-( ...onActivityResult is never called in main activity...first language is dutch..

Comment: did you use a startActivityForResult? I forgot to say sorry, because startActivity isn't enought

Comment: i can do a startActivityForResult from the broadcast receiver, but the broadcastreceiver is not causing any problems....it goes back to the main activity..and i cant sent results to that one..